# Fees and payments in ETH in polygon

Tags: solidity, evm, polygon

I'm new to polygon technology. In my contract there is a function that accepts payment. My questions are:-

1. Can gas fee be paid in ethereum ETH?
2. Can I accept payment in ethereum ETH?
3. If is ask users to convert their ethereum ETH to polygon ETH, then when they call my function there have to first approve polygon ETH(WETH) as it is an ERC20 to transfer it to my contract. Then in my function I have to call transferFrom function of WETH. Also they have to pay gas fee in Matic. Is this flow correct?

Comment: You should add the base of your question in the title for more help ;) @Radiant_Performer_39

Answer (score 1):

1/ Gas fee will be in Matic, because as you know it s a layer2 and ensure is gas cost on his own, to pay the minters.

2/ To do so you need a bridge Eth-OwnToken

3/ It seems correct, ETH---(cost converstion)--->MATIC then, Callfunction---(gas fee)--->Result